# Custom submit action with constructor not working

Tags: sitecore-forms, dependency-injection

I implemented a custom submit action and it works fine. But now I'm trying to store data to an external database using repository classes. For some reason it doesn't work if I add other interfaces in the constructor.
Here is my code snippet:

```
public class CustomSubmitAction: SubmitActionBase<string>
{
    private readonly ImessagingServiceRepository _messagingServiceRepository;

    public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData, ImessagingServiceRepository messagingServiceRepository) : base(submitActionData)
    {
        _messagingServiceRepository = messagingServiceRepository;
    }

    protected override bool TryParse(string value, out string target)
    {
        target = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(formSubmitContext, nameof(formSubmitContext));

        if (!formSubmitContext.HasErrors)
        {
            var formfields = formSubmitContext.Fields;
            ......
            // following code is mockup 
            // call repository using 
           _messagingServiceRepository.Save(model);
        }
     }
 }
```

In the log it shows this warning but when I try to step thru the code it won't even hit the breakpoint on constructor:

```
WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Modules.ExperienceForm.CustomSubmitAction. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 1. Parameter types: Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.SubmitActionData
```

If I leave constructor as default  it works perfectly.

```
public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore grabs the constructor with the signature it knows, i.e. the one with one parameter. If your submit-action doesn't have one, it'll fall back on the standard constructor of `SubmitActionBase<string>` that your custom submit-action is inheriting from.

You'll have to explicitly call the dependency injection library you use to get the implementation of `ImessagingServiceRepository`. You could do something like this to have the one-parameter constructor call your two-parameter constructor:

```
public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData)
    : this(submitActionData,
      My.DependencyInjection.GetImplementation<ImessagingServiceRepository>())
{
}

public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData, ImessagingServiceRepository messagingServiceRepository)
    : base(submitActionData)
{
    _messagingServiceRepository = messagingServiceRepository;
}
```

This way you can still have a two-parameter constructor that you call in your UnitTest with a Mock-implementation of `ImessagingServiceRepository`.